# Eliminar o transparentar "fondo" en Tkinter(Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica, background

¿Es posible hacer "transparente" el background de la raíz? Se que el marco lo puedo eliminar con overrideredirect(), pero es posible transparentar o "eliminar" ese excedente (lo que está en color gris)?

Intente con los atributos en la raíz, pero este vuelve transparente toda la ventana.

En caso de que no sea posible ¿Qué otra librería grafica me recomiendan para lograr esto?

Saludos y gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Alguna forma o libreria que sepan para hacer el fondo transparente en ubuntu? -transparent en linux no funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar `root.attributes()` para configurar un color transparente

Ten en cuenta que cualquier componente que tenga el mismo color de fondo que el color que configures como transparente va a ser reemplazado

Ejemplo:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
#Asignar un color al fondo de root (De preferencia un color que no utilices)
root['bg'] = 'grey'
#Configurar el color que va a ser transparente, debe ser el mismo que el color del fondo de root
root.attributes('-transparentcolor', 'grey')

#Todos los componentes que tengan el color de fondo igual al que configuraste como transparente van a ser transparentes
lbl = tk.Label(text='Soy transparente!', font='Helvetica 36 bold', bg='green', fg='grey')
btn = tk.Button(text='Botón', font='Helvetica 36', bg='grey', fg='blue')
canvas = tk.Canvas(bg='grey')

lbl.pack()
canvas.pack()
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Mil gracias! es exactamente lo que estaba buscando! :)

Comment: @nhydawn, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.