# Hacer "label" transparente

Tags: python, tkinter, animación, label

quiero que me ayuden a hacer label transparente en tkinter, como que el texto se muestre con una animacion que el texto aparezca transparente y se vaya poniendo normal y luego se desvanezca, como el inicio de Counter Strike Global Offensive
en pocas palabras cambiar la opacidad de un label en tkinter

Comment: Buen día, esta pregunta parece estar relacionada a [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/520112/171630).

Comment: @HeytalePazguato la respuesta que enlasas sirve para hacer a un label completamente transparente. No sirve para lograr el efecto buscado por el OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lamentablemente, en Tkinter no es posible establecer una transparencia parcial a un Label. Sin embargo, si es posible generar una imagen con transparencia y cargarla en Tkinter. Para esto vamos a usar una conocida librería de terceros llamada [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/).

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw, ImageTk

# creamos una clase derivada del objeto Label. En este caso el label actuará de contenedor de la imagen.
class AlphaLabel(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Este constructor acepta, además de los argumentos que le pasarías a un Label normal, los siguientes:
        - alpha: Debe ser un numero entero entre 0 y 255 inclusive, esto representa la transparencia del texto. Por default es 255 (opaco)
        - fg:    Es el color del texto en forma de color RGB (con formato (0 a 255, 0 a 255, 0 a 255)). Por default es (0, 0, 0) (negro)
        - font:  Debe ser una fuente de Pillow. Esta será la fuente del texto. Por default es la fuente default de Pillow.
        """
        # Eliminamos la clave alpha del diccionario kwargs y retornamos su valor. Si no existe, devuelve 255.
        # Esto nos ayudará a separar los argumentos a pasar al método extra_config de lo que le vamos a pasar al Label.
        alpha = kwargs.pop("alpha", 255)
        text  = kwargs.pop("text", "")
        fg    = kwargs.pop("fg", (0,0,0))
        font  = (kwargs.pop("font") if("font" in kwargs) else ImageFont.load_default())
        
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

        self.extra_config(alpha=alpha, text=text, font=font, fg=fg)

    def extra_config(self, *, alpha=None, text=None, font=None, fg=None):
        """
        Este constructor acepta, además de los argumentos que le pasarías a un Label normal, los siguientes:
        - alpha: Debe ser un numero entero entre 0 y 255 inclusive, esto representa la transparencia del texto. Por default es 255 (opaco)
        - fg:    Es el color del texto en forma de color RGB (con formato (0 a 255, 0 a 255, 0 a 255)). Por default es (0, 0, 0) (negro)
        - font:  Debe ser una fuente de Pillow. Esta será la fuente del texto. Por default es la fuente default de Pillow.
        """
        
        # si se pasó el argumento alpha, creamos un atributo de clase que almacenará el nuevo valor pasado.
        if(alpha is not None):
            self.alpha = alpha
        if(text is not None):
            self.text = text
        if(font is not None):
            self.font = font
        if(fg is not None):
            self.fg = fg

        # obtenemos el tamaño del texto a dibujar.
        image_size = self.font.getsize(self.text)

        # creamos una nueva imagen totalmente transparente con el tamaño que el texto necesitará.
        image = Image.new("RGBA", image_size, color=(0,0,0,0))

        # creamos el objeto que nos permitirá dibujar en la imagen.
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

        # dibujamos el texto en las coordenadas (0, 0) de la imagen.
        draw.text((0,0), self.text, font=font, fill=(*self.fg, self.alpha))

        # convertimos la imagen en un objeto compatible con tkinter (PhotoImage)
        # es importante mantener una referencia a la imagen en Python
        # (lo que se logra en este caso guardando la imagen en un atributo de un objeto que no será eliminado)
        # por favor vease:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/502518/158880
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        
        # Establecemos la nueva imagen al label.
        self["image"] = self.image

def aparicion():
    # Le sumamos 10 al alpha anterior y, si es mayor a 255, el nuevo alpha será 255. Si no, será el alpha antiguo + 10.
    label.extra_config(alpha=min(label.alpha+10, 255))

    # si el alpha del label es menor a 255, llamamos a esta función dentro de 100 milisegundos.
    if(label.alpha < 255):
        label.after(100, aparicion)
    
        

label = AlphaLabel(text="hola mundo", alpha=0)
label.pack()

# llamamos a la función aparicion dentro de 100 milisegundos
label.after(100, aparicion)
```

Comment: Gracias por responder